# How to change the name of an XML element during XML Serialization runtime (ASP.Net WebApi)

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api, xml-serialization

I am building a response to a WebAPI service call. The default XML Serializer is mostly working for me. What I need to generate is something like this:

```
<fooCollection>
  <fooMember>
    <fooType1>
      ...bunch of properties for the fooMember
    </fooType1>
  </fooMember>
  <fooMember>
    <fooType2>
      ...bunch of properties for the fooMember
    </fooType2>
  </fooMember>
</fooCollection
```

The problem I have is the `<fooType>` element is currently an object in my model called `fooType`. The element name in the response needs to have a different name depending on the type property of my `fooMember` object. This means that using things like the `[DataContract]` and `[DataMember]` attributes to give it a name other than the object name don't seem to work because they are set once and I cannot find how to change that at runtime.

My model code looks something like this:

```
  public partial class fooCollection {
    private fooCollectionMember[] memberField;

    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("fooMember")]
    public fooCollectionMember[] member { get; set;}
  }

  public partial class fooCollectionMember {
    private fooType fooTypeField;
    public fooType fooType { get; set }
  }

  public partial class fooType {
    private object fooProperty;
    // ... more properties
    public object fooProperty { get; set; }
    // ... more properties
  }
```

Is there a way during runtime/serialization that I can set what my element name will be for that `<fooType>` element?

Alternatively, is there a way I can rearrange my model so the `fooType` is not an object with the rest of the properties inside it, but is instead a property of the `fooMember` object along with all the other properties, but that when serialized the `<fooType>` element is named the value of that property and encapsulates the rest of the properties within it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My original service call get method was something like this:

```
    public FooCollection Get () {
      FooCollection foos = new FooCollection();
      // code to fill model
      return foos;
    }
```

I have found nothing that allows me to take an XML element in the response that is based on a property or object in FooCollection and change that element's name in the XML response based on the property/object's value. i.e. I cannot have a `FooProperty` property whose element generated in the XML response has a different element name for each collection item. In other words this property can only have a single element name throughout the entire XML document if I use the return-a-model-object-and-let-the-serialization-happen-automatically approach. However, I have found a workaround to allow me to change the element names however I see fit.

Rather than having my `Get()` service method return an object of the `FooCollection` type and be serialized automatically after the return I am instead returning an `HttpResponseMessage` object. This way I can manually serialize my model, manipulate it however I want, then return it as `HttpResponseMessage`.

So now my get service method can look more like this to accomplish my goal:

```
public HttpResponseMessage Get () {
  XmlSerializer xmlSerializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(FooCollection));
  System.IO.StringWriter stringWriter = new System.IO.StringWriter();
  XmlSerializerNamespaces namespaces = new XmlSerializerNamespaces();
  FooCollection foos = new FooCollection();
  // code to populate FooCollection model, assign namespaces, etc
  xmlSerializer.Serialize(stringWriter, foos, namespaces);
  // Now we can manipulate stringWriter value however is needed to replace the element names
  return new HttpResponseMessage() {
    Content = new StringContent(stringWriter.ToString(), Encoding.UTF8, "application/xml")
  };
}
```